# Modify VBO checkbox value

Tags: 6, forms, views

I would like to modify the value of my VBO checkboxes but can't figure where to hook in.

```
<input name="objects[selection][1]" id="edit-objects-selection-1" value="1" class="form-checkbox select" type="checkbox">
```

becomes

```
<input name="objects[selection][1]" id="edit-objects-selection-1" value="1-XXX" class="form-checkbox select" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be form, so you can try the following on VBO page, if it workds.

```
   function  mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
      dpm($form_id);
    }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've looked at $form in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() and there is $form['objects']['#sets'][$i]['id'] which contains the value that it uses to build the checkbox value.  But its used elsewhere and I can't modify at that source.

Answer (score 0):

The value I needed was in the $context variable in the action :|

*EDIT*
I didn't need to change the checkbox value because the value I wanted was in the actions $context variable.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's nice you found a way to success, but could you provide a code sample or more detailed explanation? Now your answer doesn't look like an answer to the question - in question you ask for hooks, in answer you talk about value, and it's confusing.